# Does disposing SPSite dispose the SPWeb automatically?

Tags: dispose

Suppose we have code:

**CASE 1:**

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    }
```

Do we need to dispose the SPWeb in this case?

**CASE 2:**

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            SPWeb web = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url).OpenWeb();
        }
```

Do we need to dispose the SPWeb in this case? Or does it get automatically disposed after the using block disposes the SPSite object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In first case `SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;` `SPWeb` does not need to be disposed as `SPWeb` is retrieved from `RootWeb`. However, in second case `SPWeb` needs to be explicitly disposed. Mere disposal of `SPSite` is not enough. So the code should look like:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

    }
}
```

Note: there is no need to create an `SPSite` object again when opening `SPweb` as it is already present.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/12/05/disposing-spweb-and-spsite-objects.aspx This articles says: "dispose for the SPSite object in position 1 will automatically dispose all SPWeb objects bound to the SPSite object.", can you check please.

Comment: It also mentions "You should dispose a SPWeb or SPSite object after the last access to a child object of this object." This is done by having the `using` statement. `using` is equivalent to `try catch finally`

Comment: Just curious, do you know how `RootWeb` is disposed by SPSite? When decompiling the SharePoint DLL I can't see where it is disposed at all. I think `m_openedWebs` are all disposed of properly, but `RootWeb` is not part of these. I know it is disposed, I just can't see where it is done

Answer (score 2):

No, we need to dispose the SPWeb object separately. 
Because we are not assigning **current SPWeb context** to the web variable.

Here,
1. We are first getting the SPSite object from current context web url
2. Then we are retrieving the SPWeb object from SPSite
3. After that we are assigning that variable to the SPWeb.

So, we need to dispose the SPWeb object separately in Case 2 to clear the garbage memory.
In Case 1: SPWeb object (web) is automiatically disposed by site.

Comment: Are you sure that:  SPWeb web = site.RootWeb; needs to be disposed?

Comment: No need. For Case 1, the web object automatically disposed by site.